# Amazon: product advertising api pagination top sellers

Tags: amazon-product-api

Is this a limitation of the amazon API?

I would like to pull data similar to this page: amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Home-Improvement-Pumps-Plumbing-Equipment/zgbs/hi/13749581/ref=zg_bs_nav_hi_1_hi

STACKOVERFLOW BREAKS THIS LINK!

am using:

```
operation: 'BrowseNodeLookup',
response_group: "BrowseNodeInfo,TopSellers"
```

The TopSeller response group only returns **10 items** and does not respond to ItemPage.

Is there a way to do item lookup without a query using a browse node and sorting by popularity?

Comment: The [this page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/680334011) link shows a 1x1 GIF. Could you update the link? Please include a longer code snippet in order to show what you are doing and how.

Comment: @simlev its super weird SO breaks the link to amazon. I've not included any referral param or anything not sure why they would do that.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 2):

The AWS documentation on the [`BrowseNodeLookup`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeLookup.html) API and the [`TopSellers`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_TopSellers.html) response group indicates that it only includes the top 10, and there is no mention of pagination.

> The TopSellers response group returns the ASINs and titles of the 10 best sellers within a specified browse node.

However, the results from `TopSellers` are basically equivalent to the results of an [`ItemSearch`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html) with [`Sort`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/APPNDX_SortValuesArticle.html) set to `salesrank`.  Therefore, you can solve pagination requirements as follows:

1. On initial load (such as a user loading a web page or opening a particular view in a mobile application), issue `BrowseNodeLookup` and retrieve `TopSellers`.  Populate some portion of the UI with information from the browse node and some other portion of the UI with the `TopSellers` results.
2. If the user never goes past the first page, then do nothing more.  (There is no need to spend time on an additional service call.)
3. As the user navigates to subsequent pages, issue `ItemSearch` with `Sort` set to `salesrank` and `ItemPage` set to the page number.  Use these results to update the portion of the web page/view in your application that was previously populated from the browse node `TopSellers`.

Note that you will still only be able to retrieve up to 10 pages worth of results. This is an `ItemSearch` API [limitation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/PagingandSortingThroughResults.html#MaximumNumberofPages).

Comment: So the first fetch would return the 10 items without any offer information. Then i could do an `ItemSearch` using the browsenode as a filter... then another one to get 20 products worth. does that sound correct?